# Just Average: CodeAcademy

Tags: python

I have been trying to crack this nut for a while. I'm trying to figure out how to get my averages to return a float to satisfy a requirement at Code Academy. I believe I satisfied the requirements for a float with my def average function. I get this error message from them... **"Oops, try again! Make sure average returns a float!"**

**These are CodeAcademy Requirements :** Write a function called get_average that takes a student dictionary as input and returns his/her weighted average. Use your average function to help. Homework is 10%, quizzes are 30% and tests are 60%.

I guess the question is...where else can I stick a float?

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
def average(list):
   return float(sum(list)/(len(list)))

def get_average(student):
    h=average(student["homework"])
    q= average(student["quizzes"])
    t= average(student["tests"])
    rez = h*0.1+q*0.3+t*0.6
    return rez

def get_class_average(studenti):
    for x in studenti:
    print x
    print get_average(x)

studenti=[alice,tyler,lloyd]
get_class_average(studenti)
```

Comment: What are Code Academy's requirements for your program?  Is `get_class_average` supposed to return a float instead of print it?

Comment: I should have posted this in the original...
"Write a function called get_average that takes a student dictionary as input and returns his/her weighted average. Use your average function to help. Homework is 10%, quizzes are 30% and tests are 60%."

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeAcademy: Just Averages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073725/codeacademy-just-averages)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your script is returning a syntax error while running.

Change :

```
def get_class_average(studenti):
for x in studenti:
print x
print get_average(x)
```

to

```
def get_class_average(studenti):
    for x in studenti:
        print x    #note the tab
        print get_average(x) #note the tab spaces
```

Because of this syntax error your script does not run completely and hence CodeAcademy cannot validate the results of your script.

I tried out your code snippet after correcting the syntax errors and am able to get the below output:

```
{'quizzes': [82.0, 83.0, 91.0], 'tests': [89.0, 97.0], 'name': 'Alice', 'homework': [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0]}
91.15
{'quizzes': [0.0, 75.0, 78.0], 'tests': [100.0, 100.0], 'name': 'Tyler', 'homework': [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0]}
79.9
{'quizzes': [88.0, 40.0, 94.0], 'tests': [75.0, 90.0], 'name': 'Lloyd', 'homework': [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0]}
80.55
```

Answer (score 0):

lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]

}

def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    float(total)
    print total /len(numbers)

def average(list):
 ave = float(sum(list))/len(list)
 return ave
def get_average(student):
 weight = average(student["homework"])*0.1 + average(student["quizzes"])*0.3 + average(student["tests"])*0.6
 return weight

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me

```
loyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
item = ["homework", "quizzes", "tests"]
students =["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = float(sum(numbers))
    total = total / len(numbers)
    return total

def get_average(student):
    homework = float(0.1 * average(student["homework"]))
    quizzes = float(0.3 * average(student["quizzes"]))
    tests = float(0.6 * average(student["tests"]))
    avg = homework + quizzes + tests 
    return avg
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finished Codecedemy, this is my code.

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
"quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
"tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
"name": "Alice",
"homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
"quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
"tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
"name": "Tyler",
"homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
"quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
"tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total)
    return total/len(numbers)
def get_average(student):
    homework_ave=average(student["homework"])
    quizzes_ave=average(student["quizzes"])
    tests_ave=average(student["tests"])
    return 0.1 * average(student["homework"]) + 0.3 *                           average(student["quizzes"]) + 0.6 * average(student["tests"])
def get_letter_grade(score):
    if 90 <= score:
        return "A"
    elif 80 <= score:
        return "B"
    elif 70 <= score:
        return "C"
    elif 60 <= score:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"
print get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd))
def get_class_average(students):
    results = []
    for student in students:
        results.append(get_average(student))
    return average(results)
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
print get_class_average(students)
print get_letter_grade(get_class_average(students))
```